# How to see if someone is exploiting your wifi

Tags: debian, wifi, internet

I'm wondering about the possibility to know who is using my wireless connection.

Lastly, my wireless connection is going to be slower and slower and probably someone is exploting that behind my back.

I'm running *Linux Debian 8* distribution on my notebook.

Some of you knows if it is possible to monitor who is using the wireless and the kind of device through which he is connected?

Can you suggest the way to do that?

Comment: what wifi access point router model do you have and who configured it?

Answer (score 1):

```
nmap -sP 192.168.0.*    #adjust the IP range according to your case
```

or

```
arp-scan -l
```

You can play with interface name setting if you have more than one. You can exclude "known" IPs or MACs with grep for example. And of course your scanning machine has to be in the same LAN as WiFi.

Answer (score 0):

If you login to your home wifi router, there is a page that will show who's connected.  You will see all devices, phones etc.  Refer to your wifi router for exact location of the menu although it should be fairly easy to find in the menu's.  You might be surprised how many wifi enabled devices you legitimately have in your home if you live with other people like family or room mates.

To access most routers you open your web browser and type 192.168.0.1 but it can be a different address.  You can click on your wifi button in the menu bar - go to network settings of your local router and look up your router ip address listed after clicking the preferences button.

Comment: there are many cases (especially in Europe) where the internet provider also provides a router to connect to the internet and there is no access to all its features. is there a program to monitor who is connected to a certain wifi network?

Comment: Exactly. In this way I cannot see how much devices are connected and, particularly, who is connected. Ideally, it would be nice to get a program to monitor it!